# Tensorflow - assigning placeholders values into variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, mnist

I'm trying to modify the TensorFlow MNIST example, so that the placeholder input values are passed to a variable for manipulation, prior to generating the results.

For instance:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# create placeholder/weights/biases
input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
input_W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
input_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

# Create the new variable
var_x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784]), trainable=False)

# Perform an arbitrary manipulation on MNIST input, and assign to var_x
for i in range(0,784):
    var_x[i].assign(input_x[i] / 2)

input_Y = tf.matmul(var_x, input_W) + input_b
```

In the example above, I'm passing placeholder values input_X into var_X, where I can perform arbitrary manipulations on the values, before multiplying by weights to get the output result.

I'm getting the following error on tf.matmul:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [784], [784,10].
```

I'm confused why, in the above example, this works:

```
tf.matmul(input_x, input_W) + input_b
```

but this doesn't:

```
tf.matmul(var_x, input_W) _ input_b
```

As both input_x and var_x should both be a 784 length vector.

I essentially want it to be exactly the same matrix multiplication you'd have in the normal MNIST example, but using a variable rather than a placeholder.

This seems like it should be super straight-forward, however I'm new to TensorFlow, and despite reading a lot of tutorials/SO questions, I haven't seen this particular scenario anywhere before.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

> As both input_x and var_x should both be a 784 length vector.

This is not exactly true. Input_x is of shape [None, 784] and your var_x is of shape [784].

Unfortunately, I don't exactly see what you are trying to do...

> I essentially want it to be exactly the same matrix multiplication you'd have in the normal MNIST example, but using a variable rather than a placeholder.

If you want to use a variable rather than a placeholder you could say

```
input_x = tf.Variable(tf.float32, preloaded_digits_numpy_array)
```

And leave the rest of the code like it is...

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry if it wasn't clear. I'm wanting to load the digits into the placeholder as normal, but do some manipulations on the values before calculating the results.

Comment: Sorry, my comment go cut off. 

I wanted to add:

So in the example above, I'm taking the placeholder fed values, and halving them. Similarly, I may want to take the placeholder values, and combine them, or average them etc. I may want to eventually do this with multiple variables, so input_x needs to be separate to the updated/matmul'd variable. 

Hope that's clearer! Cheers

Comment: Mmm, in that case, why not perform this operation using numpy before feeding it to the graph?

Comment: I'm planning to regularly take information out of the graph while it's processing, perform operations on it, then continue processing the updated values. Are you suggesting this isn't supported in TensorFlow? Thanks